# Starting a daemon process from within Python script and killing it via os.kill later

Tags: python, linux

In Linux environment, I'm trying to use python to start a daemon process if it's not already started, get the PID, and then at some point later kill that process using os.kill(pid, signel.SIGTERM). This results in the daemon process becoming defunct, if it was started from my script.

Here's the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, subprocess, time, signal, getpass

p = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '30'])

os.kill(int(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)

os.system('ps -fu ' + getpass.getuser())
```

I get the following as output:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
pchernik  7179 10629  0 16:07 pts/0    00:00:00 python3 ./boom
pchernik  7180  7179  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 [sleep] <defunct>
```

My end goal is:

- Using a .pid file check whether daemon is running
- Start daemon if not running, get PID and save it to .pid file
- Do some other stuff (socket communication with daemon)
- Stop daemon and start it again using os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

Can't use p.kill() b/c I might not have "p" to work with, if process is already started outside of this python script.

Can't use wait() as I have more than 1 process started this way.

I tried adding preexec_fn=os.setsid to Popen - doesn't seem to help

How can I start a daemon process from within Python script and completely detach it from my Python process?

Thanks,
-Pavel

Comment: Silly question, but why don't you let init/upstart/systemd (shudder) take care of the nitty gritty, and let the OS provided tools handle this for you?

Comment: This is a part of a larger script I'm putting together to do something like the following, for a third party package, that has daemons running under several developer environments:

* Start several daemon processes, if they are not already started
* Do some other stuff, that communicates with these processes
* During this "some other stuff" - some of the daemons will have to be restarted, multiple times, for changes to take effect.

Comment: I.e. I have a few developers using this tool, and it requires several daemons to be ran under individual dev environments.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent. Reuse: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize

BTW, can you modify the protocol you speak with the daemon? If yes, you could add a "terminate yourself" command to the protocol. This is cleaner than "os.kill()".

If your daemon is not written in Python you can use subprocess or [os.execv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl) to start the executable (together with daemonize).

Comment: Thanks, trying this now. The daemon is a 3P tool, so can't modify the protocol.

Comment: I don't think I can use deamonize, as it is designed to create a python daemon, not to start another executable as daemon. The pid it stores in the .pid file is that of the python process that is forked.

Comment: @PavelChernikov I updated the answer: If your daemon is not written in Python you can use subprocess or os.execv to start the executable (together with daemonize)

Comment: using deamonize will result in addition python processes running together with the actual daemon processes they started as well as the problem where deamonize pid will be that of the python process that forked, not the actual daemon. I don't think I can use deamonize here - the problem I had was solved by using os.waitpid().

Comment: @PavelChernikov with os.execv() the second Python process gets **replaced** with executable you start.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what I have to do is call os.waitpid() on the process after issuing the kill. The process is no longer defunct and is gone.